# change/remove the "virtual box" label of the integrated camera (while using host webcam in virtual box)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, webcam

I am using virtualbox to run linux mint 20.01 and I am using the host webcam in it. I want to change the name of the webcam which by default has the prefix "virtual box"

can anyone suggest how can I change the label of the webcam temporarily or permanently